# Vertx : Running a block of code outside of the eventloop

Tags: vert.x

I write a service by Vertx. My service run a function like this :

```
router.get("/report").handle(ServiceHandler::Count);
```

My `Count` function takes a long time (about from 10 to 15 minutes) and that broke the golden rule of Vertx. I'm newbie and I've tried google it but I can not find the way out.

Please help me out!
Thanks very much.

Comment: thank everyone has come here and helped me. I solved the problem. May be my English is not good enough to describe my problem but thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

In this case use a [blocking handler](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_using_blocking_handlers):

```
router.get("/report").blockingHandler(ServiceHandler::Count);
```

Note that, by default, even worker threads are monitored by the blocked thread checker. A warning for blocked workers is generated after 60 seconds.

If the processing takes several minutes, adjust [`setMaxWorkerExecuteTime`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setMaxWorkerExecuteTime-long-) and  [`setMaxWorkerExecuteTimeUnit`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setMaxWorkerExecuteTimeUnit-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) accordingly.

Comment: I've tried before I asked my question, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem is? Is it the long time the `Count` function takes and you want to know how to improve the performance of this function? Or is 10 to 15 minutes okay for you and you want to know how to let vert.x deal with this long running function? In the latter case, the blocking handler mentioned by @tsegismont would be the solution.

Comment: my Count function actually is a job takes a long time (long here not only 10 or 15 minutes, may be much more) and the thing I really want is this function runs in background, outside of even loop. I've read Vertx's document and it recommend like Mr. Tsegismont. But it's not work, may be my code get wrong somewhere i don't know. Do you have any other idea to solve this problem ???

Comment: It's hard to answer without being able to see your code. Perhaps you could expand your code example above to a [minimal reproducible example](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#worker_verticles)? Without this kind of example, my only advice would be to implement your `Count` inside a [Worker Verticle](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#worker_verticles). Worker verticles are another way to implement long-running tasks in vert.x.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing should take over 1 minute, generally you should NOT make it run via `router` from http-request.

Your `ServiceHandler::Count` function should rather return immediately with a "process started" message, and use some long-running mechanism like `SockJS` or good-ol email to notify the user about the completion.